# Is it possible to disable incremental linking by default in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Visual C++ Express 2010 gives a linker error (LNK1123) unless /INCREMENTAL:NO is selected in the linker options. I am using VC++ for teaching C++, and I have to do this for every project I create (as do the students). Is there any way to set /INCREMENTAL:NO as the default setting for new projects?

Comment: Make a new project template. Or figure out why you get `LNK1123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem turned out to be due a MS linker bug: **cvtres.exe** references a specific version of **msvcr100.dll** (msvcr100_clr0400.dll). This version of the DLL disappears when the .Net framework is updated, so **cvtres.exe** fails with LNK1123. To fix this you have to install the Visual Studio service pack. Alternatively just replace **cvtres.exe** with the updated version, which is a few bytes bigger (31056 bytes instead of 31048).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem than you but unfortunatly I don't remember what I did do to repair the installation but this link might help you, all answers in it:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d10adba0-e082-494a-bb16-2bfc039faa80/vs2012-rc-installation-breaks-vs2010-c-projects?forum=vssetup